# Is Interlocked.Increment() perform so well in VisualBasic.Net

Tags: vb.net, collections

I wrote the code in c#

```
        public void CopyTo(ICollection ObjectCollection, Array Objects, int index)
    {
        foreach (object current in ObjectCollection )
        {
            Objects.SetValue (current, index++);
        }
    }
```

when i translated to Vb.net using a converter i get the below code

```
Public Sub CopyTo(ObjectCollection As ICollection, Objects As Array, index As Integer)
For Each current As Object In ObjectCollection
    Objects.SetValue(current, System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(index),index - 1))
Next
```

End Sub

my question:- is the Vb.net method will produce the same result as in C#?

Comment: "Does it perform well" in what situation?  Hell, BogoSort performs well on a previously sorted collection. `InterlockedIncrement` is something you use because you *need* to, not because it improves performance. In this case it doesn't seem like you need it at all as `index` is a copy local to your function.

Comment: I have modified the question, thanks for your respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on an automatic converter for code is often a bad idea. Compiling code you don't understand is a surefire way to get bugs and unexpected behavior. In this case, the converter generated nonsensical code which will compile, but contains a lot that is far from necessary.

The main issue here is that C# has the `++` operator, which increments a variable inline, while VB doesn't have a comparable operator. This means that VB code comparable to the C# would look like this:

```
 For Each current As Object In ObjectCollection
    index = index + 1
    Objects.SetValue(current, index)
 Next
```

Simple, right? But the converter, it seems, looked for an inline equivalent to C#'s ++, and came up with `Interlocked.Increment`, which is used for thread-safe atomic operations, and is quite irrelevant here. Additionally, the `Math.Max` usage (which can always only return the first value) is odd, and I'm guessing is there due to some badly conveyed casting logic.

So yes, the VB code will probably be equivalent, functionally, to the C# code. But it contains pointless, useless instructions that shouldn't remain in production code.